# disable fill handle on specific column with ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid in a angular project. I would like to deactivate fill handle only on some columns but i only see a global configuration with gridOptions.

Please help me to do it.

Comment: Please include relevant code in your quesiton, rather than leaving people to guess what you may have written.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts, please find relevant code in the [ag-grid documentation page](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-range-selection-fill-handle/). I'm looking for a solution through their documentation. My code is the same as their code example.  Thanks

Comment: I was giving you advice on how to get the help you are asking for. It seems that you are not prepared to make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As the official documentation suggests, you can use `suppressFillHandle` on a specific cell to disable fill handle

doc link:
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/range-selection-fill-handle/